# How is my captcha being circumvented by a bot?

Tags: php, forms, captcha

Here's my script to check for filled in fields:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    //required fields
    if(in_array($key, $required_fields) && empty($value) && $all_required_filled){
        $error_message .= "<li>Not all required fields were filled out</li>"; 
        $valid = false;
        $all_required_filled = false;
    }
    //valid email address
    if($key == 'email'){
        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $error_message .= "<li>Invalid email format</li>";
            $valid = false; 
        }
    }
    //captcha is valid
    if($key == "captcha"){
        if((int)$value !== (int)$_SESSION['veriword']){
            $error_message .= "<li>The captcha was incorrect</li>";
            $valid = false;
        }
        else{
            $message .= "User entered {$value}. Correct answer was {$_SESSION['veriword']}";
        }
        continue;
    } 
}
```

Basically, if the captcha form field matches the session variable that the captcha plugin sets, the script prints a line in the the email that lists what the user entered, and the correct value.

When I fill out the captcha incorrectly, I can't send the form through, and get stuck on the page with an error message. Somehow, though, a spam bot is sending out the form successfully, without the line listing the form field and captcha values. So it's completely getting around the "if" statement, somehow? I'm not sure what's going on...

Comment: Mind providing all post data?

Comment: open your contact us page in browser, open dev tools and delete captcha field from form (completely), submit page

Comment: The captcha is never checked if it is not sent. So the bot just has to post all the data, without the captcha

Comment: @jfadich how is it removing the captcha field from the form?

Comment: Forms are just one way to submit data to a server. Bots often just make post requests directly to a server, bypassing the form entirely.

Comment: Yeah - the outer check for the $key-field matching 'captcha' is not very smart. You should check for a complete set of entries, containing values, not check for an existing $key-value. As for the bot, removing a captcha field is a piece of cake - it's not filling out the form, it's posting automatically to the processing part of the form.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie check for a complete set of entries? Can you provide an example, please? Would that stop the bot from removing the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping over `$_POST`, check the the required inputs explicitly:

```
if (isset($_POST['captcha'])) {
    if (intval($_POST['captcha']) !== $_SESSION['veriword']) {
        $error_message .= "<li>The captcha was incorrect</li>";
        $valid = false;
    }
} else {
    $error_message .= "<li>The captcha was not submitted</li>";
    $valid = false;
}
```